# How to Make For Loop Django template. i was makeing a pagination in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-pagination

```
{% for i in paginated_queryset.num_pages %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor%}
```

paginated_quertser.num_pages = 9

I want to output like this  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I also read django pagination document but in the document not given example like this and I am beginner in django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the [**`.page_range`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.page_range) of the `Paginator` of the page:

```
{% for i in paginated_queryset.paginator.page_range %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if this is the `Paginator` (not the `Page`), with:

```
{% for i in paginator.page_range %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```